# Conditional rendering is always FALSE

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that fetch informations from Redux Store. To initialize store I am calling dispatch function that populates state via AJAX call.

Problem that I am facing is that conditional rendering is always FALSE. I even debug statement in console and it outputs TRUE but inside conditional rendering it is always FALSE (it skips rendering child component)

Here is code I am using:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.routeInfo()     
}

render() {


    console.log(Object.keys(this.props.inboundRoute).length !== 0);
    //After dispatch and redux state changes this outputs to TRUE!


    return (

        <div className="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
             //This statement is always FALSE
            {Object.keys(this.props.inboundRoute).length !== 0 &&

            <div className={`${this.props.match.params.ticketType !== "2" ? "col-md-12" : "col-md-6"}`}>
                <TicketInfo/>
            </div>
            }

            <BillingInfo/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Redux state initialization:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    inboundRoute: state.passenger.inboundRoute,
    returnRoute: state.passenger.returnRoute,
};
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {routeInfo})(PassengerList));
```

**EDIT**

It seems that props is always empty once return method inside render is triggered. Does someone knows why?

Comment: Try storing `this.props.inboundRoute` in a variable. Also, I think it is better to do `inboundRoute.length > 0` instead of `inboundRoute.length !== 0`